# Questions about Coffeescript/Javascript conditional results

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have this Coffeescript:

```
console.log 'TEST'
console.log index
console.log (index is not 0)
console.log (index > 0)
unless index is 0
    console.log "passed test"
```

This is the compiled Javascript:

```
console.log('TEST');
console.log(index);
console.log(index === !0);
console.log(index > 0);
_results.push(index !== 0 ? console.log("passed test") : void 0);
```

This is the console output

```
TEST
0
false
false
passed test
TEST
1
false
true
passed test
```

Question 1) Why does `(index is not 0)` return `false` when `index` is 1? `(index > 0)` returns `true` for 1, so why doesn't `(index is not 0)`?

Question 2) Why does the `unless index is 0` test get passed when `index` is 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does `(index is not 0)` return `false` when `index` is 1? `(index > 0)` returns `true` for 1, so why doesn't `(index is not 0)`?

CoffeeScript doesn't use `is not` for inequality, it uses `!=` and `isnt`. By looking at the compiled code, we can see that it's actually interpreting `(index is not 0)` as `(index is (not 0))`.

> Why does the `unless index is 0` test get passed when `index` is 0?

When [I tried it myself](http://jeremybanks.github.com/coffee-script/#src%3af%20%3D%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20for%20index%20in%20%5B0%2C%201%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log%20%27TEST%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log%20index%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log%20%28index%20is%20not%200%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log%20%28index%20%3E%200%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20unless%20index%20is%200%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log%20%22passed%20test%22%0A%0Af%28%29) the test **did not** pass. This behaviour is probably being caused by something in your testing code that you haven't included in your post.

Comment: Exactly. Confusing `is not` with `isnt` in CoffeeScript is a common mistake.

Answer (score 1):

This is fiddly:

```
console.log(index === !0);
```

It gets treated in the same way as:

```
console.log(index === (!0));
```

`0`  is a falsey constant, so you could replace `(!0)` with `true`. The real code is then:

```
console.log(index === true);
```

So it will only log "true" when `index` is boolean true without type coercion.